# Cutting specific segments in a image with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

[image: Sample image]

I have scanned copy of a page which consists of multiple questions.
Now I want to cut individual questions individually. example :
[image: individual question]

The logic i am using is : 1. Finding Contours

```
kernal = np.ones((2, 20), np.uint8)
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(self.img, kernal, iterations=1)
im2, contr, _ = \
        cv2.findContours(img_dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_ctrs = sorted(contr, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
```

- Now we know that question numbers are the places where we want to cut the image from and all numbers lie before a margin..So cutting image at the point where x co-ordinate of the countour is less than specific margin would be good place to begin with.

But the problem is it doesn't always get contours on those question numbers .

Are there any other more efficient and accurate ways to cut the questions out of a whole page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest and first method I would try:

First, you can easily crop the two columns by finding the location of long vertical line that separates them.

On each of the columns: If your document is scanned in an aligned manner, you can view the horizontal projection of one column. I can observe that there is a significant gap between the ending of each question and starting of another.

When you compute the horizontal projection, wherever you get many zeros, that denotes the ending of a question and beginning of the next.